# Multiple different forms in one ajax php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Due to language limitations I might not understood how to ask Google about what I want to accomplish, but I hope you will understand.

I have three forms which i want to show on the same page without refresh. First form submits action to php which determines which function (with yet another form) to show. But buttons interfere and I am nowhere near what I wanted to do.

Index.php is supposed to send user input to calculator.php which then opens next form depending on value:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" formaction="calculator.php">
<input id="form1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<div id="parseSecondForm"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#form1').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type: $(this).attr('method'),
  url: $(this).attr('formaction'),
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#parseSecondForm').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
  },
  success: function(data){
    $('#parseSecondForm').html(data);
  }
});
});
});
</script>
```

calculator.php receives user input and echoes next form in #parseSecondForm div in index.php:

```
if (form1 === '1') {
 echo '
   <form id="form2" method="post" formaction="form2.php">
   <input id="form2" type="submit" value="Submit" />
   <div id="thankyou"></div>
   <!--submit saves php result in MySQL and thanks the user in next div-->
 ';
}
 else {
  echo '
   <form id="form3" method="post" formaction="form3.php">
   <input id="form3" type="submit" value="Submit" />
   <div id="thankyou"></div>
   <!--submit saves php result in MySQL and thanks the user in next div-->
 ';
}
```

I tried to echo modified javascript from index.php, but it just resets all the forms.

Maybe there are some form scripts designated for the cause or any other ideas how can I fix the issue?

Comment: You could hide/show parts of these different forms and then handle one submit at the end?

Comment: For one, you have the same ID for the `<form>` and the `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript/HTML you cannot have two items with the same IDs:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" formaction="calculator.php">
<input id="form1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

`form1` can be used only once.

Same for the php dynamically created forms.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question